# POST-Request with token in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I try to do a request POST with angular and I can't a simple request because my login is protected by a token. 
I try to do the next request:

```
angular.module('app.main').controller('AppCntl', ['$scope', '$http',
function($scope, $http) {

  'use strict';

var requete = {
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'http://localhost:8081/oasp4j-sample-server/login',
  headers:{
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '73a06e37-e849-443a-b816-2cd3b9f5f162',
    'Cookie'
  }
}
  $http({requete}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    console.log('OK');
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    console.log('NOK');
  });
}]);
```

With Postman this request works.
I obtained my token :

```
{
"token": "73a06e37-e849-443a-b816-2cd3b9f5f162",
"parameterName": "_csrf",
"headerName": "X-CSRF-TOKEN"
}
```

And I have the next error:

```
-angular.js:11598 Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'AppCntl' is not a function, got undefined
-http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.10/ng/areq?p0=AppCntl&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
    at angular.js:63
    at assertArg (angular.js:1577)
    at assertArgFn (angular.js:1587)
    at angular.js:8422
    at angular.js:7596
    at forEach (angular.js:331)
    at nodeLinkFn (angular.js:7583)
    at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:7075)
    at publicLinkFn (angular.js:6954)
    at angular.js:1451
```

The first error is caused by the "header" and the second is caused by the security.

Comment: Isnt this wrong? $http({requete}) should be $http(requete) ??

Comment: I only see one error, which says that `AppCntl` can't be found. You seem to have defined that, though, so it may be something else, like a syntax error. My bet is that you should set the `Cookie` value to something (`Cookie: 'test'`), otherwise that whole file won't be parsed. Also what @yBrodsky said.

Comment: like @yBrodsky said that's an error

Comment: Also @JeffHuijsmans is right. There you have 2 errors

Comment: I had the sames errors even if I correct my errors :(